# What are the problems of subtyping?

Tags: type-systems, subtypes

I've heard often that Subtyping breaks some important and useful properties: many nice innovations developed by pure programming language researchers can't be brought to Java or C++ because of subtyping. They say that the language Rust avoided Subtyping for this reason.

Is such a claim correct?

What are some cool things that cannot be applied to languages with subtyping?

Is any language offering Subtyping completely cursed and incompatible with a lot of cool features? Or only the pieces of code that use subtyping are incompatible?

Could you try to explain what it means to someone coming from C++ with little theoretical knowledge?

I searched for explanations and found:

- [Why avoid subtyping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266596/why-avoid-subtyping) on Stack Overflow, but the top answer uses notions and a language I can't understand.
- [Why is it bad to have one mechanism for inheritance and subtyping?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279529/why-is-it-bad-to-have-one-mechanism-for-inheritance-and-subtyping). They explain why it's bad to have a single mechanism for interface inheritance + implementation inheritance. Not why subtyping per se is bad.
- [Subtyping, Subclassing, and Trouble with OOP](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Subtyping/#Problem-cause). The example they make misuses inheritance IMHO: CSet should be composed by CBag, not inherit it. But I think it's possible to use  Subtyping/Subclassing correctly, for other tasks.

Comment: Let’s be honest: many innovations of pure programming language researchers are of no added value to solve real world problems. This being said, nobody is obliged to use sub-typing in the language that offer it. So the existence of sub-typing seems not a good excuse for not implementing innovation that are meant to work without it. And the potential mis-use of sub-typing is not sufficient to curse it either.

Comment: @Christophe: sure, but since this is a topic that sometimes pops up when discussing programming languages, I would like to understand more what it means, even if it has no impact on the code I write.

Comment: A very practical downside is you can't have contiguous arrays, since you don't know how much memory a subtype might occupy. Workarounds are using liked lists or only store references in the array, but both have very serious performance implications.

Answer (score 3):

> Is such a claim correct?

It's not incorrect? I mean, subtyping does mean that you don't know what the exact type is for operations - you just know it's "at least" a type. That limits some analysis and optimization that can be done at compile time.

> Is any language offering Subtyping completely cursed and incompatible with a lot of cool features?

Yes, as soon as the type system has subtyping, you need something like sealed or final types to make the non-subtyping assumptions. And even then, as soon as you hit interfaces or a non-final type all bets are off. In practice, that means that you can't take advantage of things.

> What are some cool things that cannot be applied to languages with subtyping?

There's probably a lot more, but stuff like [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) become a *loooot* harder in a system that also has subtyping.

Comment: I didn't know about dependent types (found this that explains them well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9374698/13255785). I'm wondering what else is broken by subtyping (what kind of analysis or optimizations?). It seems that Rust went a long way to avoid subtyping, and many are praising Rust for that, yet it doesn't have dependent types.

Comment: @Helloer - I suspect Rust’s memory management would become untenable if it couldn’t know at compile time the exact type stored at a pointer (but I don’t know the language well enough to say for certain).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the problems with subtyping can be observed in C++, which supports subtyping and several features that are fundamentally incompatible with it.

C++ "solves" that by putting the responsibility of considering these problems on the application developer.

One major issue is memory layout - as the size of objects/instances is not known at compile time, objects cannot be stored in tightly packed contiguous memory in a layout that is known at compile time.

In C++, one of the symptoms of this is called [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

This is basically because subtyping is incompatible with the way C (which does not have subtyping) defined the memory layout of stucts, pointers and pointer arithmetic, the meaning of dereferencing a pointer, variable assignment and pass-by-value semantics. C++ introduced subtyping, but also kept most of the other features compatible with C.

What this means is that seemingly simple things like assignments and passing parameters to functions are potentially dangerous operations that the programmer needs to carefully consider, and the compiler cannot statically detect many of the potential problems.

So if you want C-like features in a safe way, you cannot do subtyping - this is where Rust is coming from.

An alternative is the Java way - drop the C-like features, accept that there are no composites with non-primitive members, all non-primitve field members are references, no manipulation of reference values, no pointer arithmetic, calling a method is always by value (but the values are all primitives or references).